# What is the expected (average) range of H(+1), T(-1) with n trials?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let n be the number of trials in a coin toss where each H is +1, T is -1, and we start at 0. Both H and T have a probability of .5. What is the average range of the distribution after n trials?

Comment: What does average range mean exactly? There is the possible range of values with positive probability, but what is an average range?

Comment: It means after n trials there is a certain possible range the distribution can have. After 1 it’s 1 as it goes to either (0,1) or (0,-1). Both of those have a range of 1. After 2 trials the average range is 1.5 as there are 4 possibilities (0,1,2), 0,1,0), (0,-1,0), (0,-1,-2). Two of those have a range of 1 and two have a range of 2. So the average range is (1+1+2+2)/4=6/4=1.5. After 3 trials there are 8 possibilities. (0,1,2,3)=3, (0,1,2,1)=2,(0,1,0,1)=1,(0,1,0,-1)=2, and the mirror image going to -1 first. In this case it’s (1+2+2+3)*2/8=2. In the case of 4 trials it’s 19/8.

Comment: So after 100 trials it can have a maximum range of 100 and a minimum range of 1. The average range is going to fall somewhere between those two scenarios obviously.